# Is the `config.yml` file what I need to customize the organization templates for the new-issue page on GitHub?

Tags: github

This [pylance GH link](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/new/choose) renders the new-issue page as

[image]

whereas [my own new-issue page](https://github.com/liyi93319/deeplearner/issues/new/choose) is rendered as

[image]

which, I guess, is using some kind of blank-issues

per [GH doc](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#configuring-the-template-chooser), I need to add a `config.yml` file to the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE` folder.

However, there isn's a `config.yml` file in [pylance GH `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE` folder](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/tree/main/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE).

Is the `config.yml` file what I need for the new-issue page pointed out by the red arrow? or I misunderstood the GH doc?

Answer (score 1):

The `config.yml` is used to generate links outside of GitHub. For example to invite users to use stackoverflow to ask questions instead doing so through GitHub issues.

To add template choices (as you have in the red square), you need to add template files in the form of `.md` files in the .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE folder. You can see example of those template files in the [pylance GH .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE folder](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/tree/main/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE)